# Hopf fibration. Checking local triviality.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, hopf-fibration

I know that similar question were asked and answered but I want to finish this very construction. In other answers different approaches are used (like construction of  sections). I would like to know if there exists the inverse to the map defined below.

Fix the notation.

$$S^3 = \{(z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^2 \;| \; |z|^2 + |w|^2 = 1     \},$$

$$p: S^3 \to \mathbb{C}P^1, \; (z, w) \mapsto (z:w) \; (\text{homogeneous coordinates})$$

I am showing local triviality. I choose an open set

$$U_w = \{ (z:w) \; | \; w \neq 0 \} \cong \mathbb{C},$$

take its preimage

$$p^{-1}(U_w) = \{ (z,w) \subset S^3 \; | \; w \neq 1 \} $$

and construt a trivialization map

$$ \phi: p^{-1}(U_w) \to U_w \times S^1, \; (z,w) \mapsto ( (z:w), \frac{w}{|w|}). $$

Obviously $p = p_1\phi$, where $\pi_1: U_w \times S^1 \to U_w$ the canonical projection.

So it is almost it. But I fail to construct the inverse map to $\phi$.

Comment: Hint: the coset $[z:w]$, $w\neq0$, has a unique representative which lies in $S^3$ and whose second coordinate is a positive real number.

Comment: Sorry, I still can’t write the formula.

Comment: $([z:w],\lambda)=(\left[\frac{|w|}{w} z:|w|\right],\lambda)\mapsto (\lambda\frac{|w|}{w}z,\lambda|w|)$